# Core Data ANY ANY multi INNER JOIN

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I've got a CoreData model that has a big list of searchable 'recipe' objects. For search efficiency I have a referenced model called 'keywords' that simply has a 'term' property (indexed). The term is a single word, processed and normalized from the 'recipe's name.

So for example, if a recipe was called Crème Brûlée, it would have two keywords of 'creme' and 'brulee', then I also normalize the user's search so they can use accented words to find non accented words, and vice versa.

When the user searches I take the string, normalize then split by whitespaces. Search recipe results must have keywords starting with all of the split search components.

I create a dynamic predicate which grows based on the number of words the user is searching for.

If you were searching for 'crem' the predicate would become something like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY keywords.term BEGINSWITH %@", @"crem"]
```

If you searched for 'crem bru':

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY keywords.term BEGINSWITH %@ AND ANY keywords.term BEGINSWITH %@", @"crem", @"bru"]
```

**Now, the problem I'm facing.**

With a single word, this is blazing fast. I'm able to run it on a 3GS with no noticeable lag with live search suggestions. The problem comes when you add subsequent words to your search. I've looked at the SQL output and I think the problem is that CoreData is doing an INNER JOIN per "ANY keywords.term BEGINSWITH", but if I rewrite the query myself I could simply do it with a single INNER JOIN.

**Running on a 3GS:**

Single word (0.0262 seconds):

> CoreData: sql: SELECT DISTINCT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.ZID, t0.ZNAME
>   FROM ZCDRECIPE t0 JOIN Z_4RECIPES t1 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_5RECIPES ***JOIN
>   ZCDKEYWORD*** t2 ON t1.Z_4KEYWORDS = t2.Z_PK WHERE 
>   NSCoreDataStringSearch( t2.ZTERM, ?, 8, 0) ORDER BY t0.ZNAME
>
> CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: **0.0262s**

Multiword (0.2996 seconds):

> CoreData: sql: SELECT DISTINCT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.ZID, t0.ZNAME
>   FROM ZCDRECIPE t0 JOIN Z_4RECIPES t1 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z_5RECIPES ***JOIN
>   ZCDKEYWORD*** t2 ON t1.Z_4KEYWORDS = t2.Z_PK JOIN Z_4RECIPES t3 ON
>   t0.Z_PK = t3.Z_5RECIPES ***JOIN ZCDKEYWORD*** t4 ON t3.Z_4KEYWORDS = t4.Z_PK
>   WHERE ( NSCoreDataStringSearch( t2.ZTERM, ?, 8, 0) AND 
>   NSCoreDataStringSearch( t4.ZTERM, ?, 8, 0)) ORDER BY t0.ZNAME
>
> CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: **0.2996s**

You can see even though it's looking at the same table, CoreData is INNER JOINing with ZCDKEYWORD more than just once.

In my predicate is there a way to make it only load the keywords table once into the join?

Thanks

Comment: How are you constructing your predicates? With strings?

Comment: With strings, they equivalent to the code in my post, but generated through a for loop so each word the user types has it's own ANY match

Answer (score 2):

Try using the compound predicate syntax. I had very good results with this setup in a similar situation.

```
for (NSString *s in words) {
   finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
     @[finalPredicate, [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
         @"ANY keywords.term BEGINSWITH %@", s]]];
}
```

---

**Edit**:

After looking up my old solution, I realised that you are maybe doing the lookup the wrong way round. It makes sense. You have more than one `keywords` lookup, so there will be two joins.

It might be better to derive the data you want from the other entity in the relationship. The predicate should refer directly to the keyword entity:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"term BEGINSWITH %@", s];
```

And deriving the end result should be just one in-memory lookup:

```
searchResults = [searchResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY keywords IN %@", fetchedKeywords]];
```

Comment: This still does two joins in the SQL query CoreData does under the hood.

Comment: Thinking about it, maybe you have to do the lookup the other way round. See my edit.

Comment: Where does the first 'searchResults' array come from in your 2nd code snippet? If it's all in memory, I've got thousands of rows so I don't know how well that will work.

Comment: Also if it needs to reference a many to many table for each iteration of the filter this may be slower than my current implementation :(

Comment: Core Data provides the mechanism of "faulting", so that even a large array of objects is not a too big strain on memory. The first `searchResults` would be the first result after typing in one letter, what else? Filtering array in memory should not be a performance problem. -- BTW, this same pattern is described in a WWDC 2011 video.

Comment: I was trying this before and noticing that in the array CoreData was faulting each one individually and doing a select query to get the keywords. I ended up doing some smart caching and threading on my current code, thanks for the advice though.